# AFrame font loads as blank blocks

Tags: aframe

Hey all I'm trying to load fonts from the [AFrame Google Font repository](https://github.com/etiennepinchon/aframe-fonts). However, I'm getting blank blocks for the letters of my `a-text`:

[image]

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the material of the text to `msdf`, in order to use the Google fonts.

Ex.

```html
<a-text material="msdf" value="Hello" font="assets/fonts/Raleway/Raleway-Regular.json"></a-text>
```